# Different callback when widget changed by user/programatically

Tags: python, callback, tkinter

I have a python tkinter GUI app with a piece of code like this:

```
    #on/off
    self.on_off_label=Label(app,text="ON/OFF:")
    self.on_off=StringVar(app)
    #self.on_off.set("off" if self.lastStatus["on"]==0 else "on")
    self.on_off_button=OptionMenu(app,self.on_off,"on","off")
    self.on_off.trace("w",self.on_off_changed)
```

This `OptionMenu` is supposed to switch a remote device on/off. But this device is periodically sending its status back to app variable (lets call it status). The problem is now the `on_off_changed` callback behaviour.
If the user changes `OptionMenu` value, I want to send a command to this remote device to switch itself on/off. But when this device sends a different status (user uses a device switch) than the one displayed in `OptionMenu`, I just want to set right value according to remote device state an don't send any commands to it (sync it with GUI).
How can this be achieved? The only solution I came up with is a global boolean flag.

I hope my problem is understandable, thanks for suggestions.

**EDIT:**
This is the function that receives status from device periodically

```
def update():
  status=getStatus()#dict like {"power":on, etc.} is recieved

  if "power" in status and self.on_off.get()!=status["power"]:

    self.on_off.set(status["power"])
```

Problem is that `on_off_change()` bind to OptionMenu is triggered, which I don't want now.

Comment: And where is function which receive `status` from device ? It will be the best place to upgrade data in OptionMenu.

Comment: Now I understand problem :) I got it in other GUIs or in other languages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use extra variable** - I call it `can_change_it = True`.
And you can set it `False` in `update()` before `self.on_off.set()`.
`on_off_changed()` have to check `if can_change_it:` before it do something
and it have to set it `True` again at the end.

**Other method** - remove `trace` for that moment:

`trace()` return uniqe tracer number/name and you have to remeber it.

```
self.trace_id = self.on_off.trace("w",self.on_off_changed)
```

then you can remove it in `update()` before `set()` and set it again after `set()`

```
trace_vdelete('w', self.trace_id )
self.on_off.set(status["power"])
self.trace_id = self.on_off.trace("w",self.on_off_changed)
```

Tkinterbook (on effbot.org): [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: Thanks furas, I thought that there could be a solution in which callback function receives implicit parameters (like event,issuer etc.), but when I examined it there seems to be nothing useful.

Comment: You can check example with `callback(*args)` in `Tkinterbook - The Variable Classes` and print `args` maybe there are some usefull information in this situation.